# How to use just one column page in documents?

Tags: two-column, geometry

I am writing in latex using this geometry

```
\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{report} 

\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}
```

Now in the middle of documents I need to used normal page instead of splitting it into two column for that page. How can I set that page normal?

Comment: Insert `\onecolumn` before where you like to star with one column page. Note, one column will start on the next page. For returnig beg to two column page, insert `\twocolumn` at end of one column page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Consider using multicol

Although the answer by Zarko is a nice answer, I think the white space between the two pages when changing between the number of columns is not very pleasing. As al alternative perhaps use the `multicol` package and switch between the two.

## Using `multicol`

```latex
\documentclass[landscape,letterpaper]{report} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\lipsum
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

## Using `\onecolumn`

(As per Zarko's comment)

```latex
\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{report} 
\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\onecolumn
\lipsum
\twocolumn
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

## Comparison of output

[image]